# Translating Ajax request from Javascript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax, xml

I'm working with Ajax for the first time and I'm trying to translate an ajax request from javascript to jquery and can't figure out how to do it.
Here is my javascript code:

```js
function aaa(track_id) {
 var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 req.open("get", "list.php?tr=" + track_id, true);
 req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 req.onreadystatechange = bbb;
 req.send();
}
    
function bbb(e) {
  if(e.target.readyState == 4 && e.target.status == 200) {
    antwort = e.target.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("title").firstChild.nodeValue = antwort.getElementsByTagName("ti")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("artist").firstChild.nodeValue = antwort.getElementsByTagName("art")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
  }
};
```

And here is the list.php:

```html
<?php
   header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");

   $con = mysqli_connect("", "root", "", "music");
   $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE track_id = " . $_GET["tr"]);
   $dset = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

   echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
   echo "<data>";
   echo " <tr>" . $dset["track_id"] . "</tr>";
   echo " <ti>" . $dset["title"] . "</ti>";
   echo " <art>" . $dset["artist"] . "</art>";
   echo "</data>";
?>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not related to your question, but you are exposed to SQL injections by concatenating user input to queries. This is very dangerous. You should use a function to sanitize such as http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php, or better yet, prepared queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the other answers will "do the job", there are some refinements you can make.

jQuery has a specific [get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method which simplifies things, and in addition, you can put the data into an object passed to the `get` or `ajax` call instead of appending it to the url as in other answers:

```javascript
function aaa(track_id) {
  $.get( 'list.php',
    { tr: track_id },
    function(data) {
      var $antwort = $(data.responseXML);
      $("#title").text($antwort.find("ti").text());
      $("#artist").text($antwort.find("art").text());
    }
    );
}
```

Another improvement is to structure it as a Promise:

```
function aaa(track_id) {
  $.get( 'list.php',
    { tr: track_id }
  ).done( function(data) {
      var $antwort = $(data.responseXML);
      $("#title").text($antwort.find("ti").text());
      $("#artist").text($antwort.find("art").text());
  });
}
```

The advantage of this is that you can chain error handling onto this relatively easily.

Turning to `list.php`, there are a few problems with it.

It would probably be better returning JSON instead of XML, as that would reduce the complexity of the `success` code, but obviously you can't do things like that if other applications expect an XML API.

```php
<?php

// protect against MySQL injection by using parameters...

$query = '
  SELECT track_id AS tr, title as ti, artist as art
  FROM tracks
  WHERE track_id=?';


$mysqli = new mysqli("", "root", "", "music");

// this needs more error checking...
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $query);
$stmt->bind_param( 's', $_GET['tr']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$dset = $result->fetch_assoc();

// simpler to return JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $dset);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick replies! But I can't get it to work, I tried this:

` $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.cover_small_hover').on('click', function(){
    $.get( 'list.php',
      { tr: 11 }    //this is an example track_id
   ).done( function(data) {
        var $antwort = $(data.responseXML);
        $("#title").text($antwort.find("ti").text());
        $("#artist").text($antwort.find("art").text());
    });
 }
)}; `

Comment: I'm sorry for the formatting, I've stared at code for too long to understand the mini markdown

Comment: Use the browser debugger to check the method is being accessed, and that the GET request is performed

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of making an AJAX in jQuery is [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax). You can also put the XML in the response in to a jQuery object and traverse that to find the values you require. Given the logic you've shown, you could implement it like this:

```
function aaa(track_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'list.php',
    data: { tr: track_id },
    success: function(data) {
      var $antwort = $(data.responseXML);
      $("#title").text($antwort.find("ti").text());
      $("#artist").text($antwort.find("art").text());
    }
  });
}
```

This is assuming that the `firstChild` of the targeted elements is a textNode.

Answer (score 0):

[`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method is used to perform an AJAX (asynchronous HTTP) request.

```js
function aaa(track_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "list.php?tr=" + track_id,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
      bbb(result);
      }
  });
}
    
function bbb(e) {
  
    antwort = e;
    document.getElementById("title").firstChild.nodeValue = antwort.getElementsByTagName("ti")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("artist").firstChild.nodeValue = antwort.getElementsByTagName("art")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
};
```